# Django - clean_field() is not being called for updates on admin inline form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I can not figure out why a clean_field() method is not being called for an inline form that is updated on an admin view.  The code I have seems straight-forward (see synopsis below).

When I modify the Primary form through admin interface (`http://admin/..../primary/1/`),  as expected, I see:

- Admin.PrimaryAdminForm.clean_myfield() called
- Admin.PrimaryAdminForm.clean() called
- Model.Primary.clean() called

However, when I modify the Primary as seen as an inline on the Admin view of Membership (`http://admin/..../membership/1/`),  I only see:

- Model.Primary.clean() called

I have tried placing the "def clean_myfield(self):" method in the following locations but can not see it get executed from the Membership inlined Primary form:

- Model.Primary.clean_myfield
- Admin.PrimaryAdmin.clean_myfield
- Admin.PrimaryAdminForm.clean_myfield
- Admin.PrimaryAdminInline.clean_myfield

Is there somewhere else this clean_myfield code should be placed?

I have read (and reread) the Django docs on [forms and field validation][docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation] which gives a great coverage, but there's nothing on inline validation.  I've also read docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin,  but no help for inline specific validation.  Is there other documentation on this?

---> **Answered by Austin** provided a doc reference to: "If not specified" (see his link) , which implies the answer.  I added a [request to improve](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20023) the documents on this topic.

After further experimenting I found a workaround by putting code in the Model.Primary.clean() method:

```
def clean(self):
    data = self.myfield
    data += "_extra" # not actual cleaning code 
    self.myfield = data
```

**So the question remains**: Why is Model.clean() seem to be the only place to put admin inline form validation and not in a clean_myfield(self) method?

---> **Answered by Austin**.  I needed add `form = PrimaryAdminForm` to PrimaryInline.  With this addition, PrimaryAdminForm.clean_myfield(self) is called when PrimaryInline myfield is updated on Membership form.  Code ordering was updated due to the added form reference.

**Code synopsis:**

*No forms.py file*  -- all models are updated through admin interface

*models.py:*

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=NAME_LENGTH,
        null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Membership Name Tag",
        help_text="Name of membership" )

class Primary(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="User Name")
    membership = models.OneToOneField(Membership, verbose_name="Membership Name")
    myfield = models.CharField("My Field", max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)


    # clean method altered as in Update comment 
    # Why must this be here? Why not in clean_myfield(self)
    def clean(self):
        data = self.myfield
        data += "_extra" # not actual cleaning code 
        self.myfield = data
```

*admin.py:*

```
class MembershipAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership

class PrimaryAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Primary

    def clean_myfield(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['myfield']
        data += "_extra" # not actual cleaning code 
        return unicode(data)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PrimaryAdminForm, self).clean()
        # not actual cleaning code 
        return cleaned_data

# EDIT2: Moved PrimaryInline so it's defined after PrimaryAdminForm 
class PrimaryInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Primary
    form = PrimaryAdminForm   #EDIT2 as recommended by Austin
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
    verbose_name_plural = 'Primary Member'
    fieldsets = ((None, {'classes': ('mbship', ),
                         'fields': ('user', 'myfield')}), )

class MembershipAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MembershipAdminForm

    # inlines
    inlines = [PrimaryInline, ]

    fieldsets = ((None, {'classes': ('mbship',),
                         'fields': ('name'), }), )

class PrimaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PrimaryAdminForm
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'user', 'status', 'date_used' )
    search_fields = ['user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'user__email'] 

    fieldsets = ((None, {'classes': ('mbship',), 
                         'fields': ('user', 'membership', 'myfield'), }), )

    def clean_myfield(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['myfield']
        data += "_extra" # not actual cleaning code 
        return unicode(data)
```

Comment: Updated to reflect Austin's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Validation occurs on `ModelForm` objects, not `ModelAdmin` objects.  If you want to override any clean methods then you have to create your own `ModelForm` descendent for each required model.

In your example, the `PrimaryInline` class does not specify a `form`.  [If not specified](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.form), the form used will be a `ModelForm`, which doesn't have any of your custom clean methods.

Try this:

```
class PrimaryInline(admin.StackedInline):
    # ... existing code ...
    form = PrimaryAdminForm
```

This will now use your custom `PrimaryAdminForm` with associated `clean()` methods.

Comment: Thanks Austin!  I wish the django docs had an example showing both model and form specified for the same class definition.  I requested a doc update.  Sorry, I'm to new to uptick your answer (I'll come back someday to do it).